# Fetch single unique row from database in Laravel

Tags: laravel

If i want to fetch single row by id i can use:

```
$flight = App\Flight::find(1);
```

Is there any method, to get a single row by other column. i.e. unique "hash" column, that returns an error, when there is more occurences of hash and returns the rown, when its unique?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that

```
$flight = App\Flight::where('your_column','your_value')->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could even use this for exception handling cases

```
$flight = App\Flight::where('column', '=', 'value')->firstOrFail();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right you want to find a row not just by 'id' also by 'name' for example. If that's the case you can use `where` like this:

```
$flight = App\Flight::where('name', ':query')->first();
```

You can read more about it here: [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#where-clauses)